# Should I answer responses to goodbye email

Tags: resignation, team

I wrote a formal good-bye email after quitting my job. I received some answers via Slack which lead to small talks, which is fine. However, some answer with their good-byes in the email thread. Is it rude if I do not answer them ?

Example of responses:

- Thank you XXX and good luck on your future projects.
- Thank you and hope to see you again during XXX event.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it rude if I do not answer them?

No, it's not rude, you have already said goodbye, the rest is implied.

Answer (score 1):

If their response is a generic "Thank you XXX and good luck on your future projects." there is no need to respond.

If it is long, or detailed, or in someway it would be viewed as requiring a response, take the response out of the email chain, and respond to that person alone.

If you used the company email system or company resources like slack, then it is assumed that you had logged out and lost the ability to participate right after you sent the goodbye email.

Answer (score 0):

It is not rude but I t would be better if you replied to them as confirmation you received their wishes it will be nice but in separate email or separate slack message.